# "Celda"(Cell )Could not be resolved Creating a List Class

Tags: c++, list, c++11, package

guys I have a problem I don't know why this problem appears in the second function. What I am trying to do is to recreate the "List" class in c++. Will add the .h and .cpp. In the function "~List", "Celda"(Cell) works completely that is a struct, but in the third "List & operator=(const List & otralis)", the program doesn't recognize Zelda as a variable !.

I am working on Eclypse Oxygen.

List.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_

template <typename datatype>
class List {
private:
    struct Celda{
        datatype ch;
        Celda *anterior;
        Celda*siguiente;
    };

public :
    List();
    List(const List & otra);
    ~List();
    List & operator=(const List & otralis);
    int size();
    bool isEmpty();
    void clear();
    datatype & front();
    datatype & back();
    void push_front(datatype & rhs);
    void push_back(datatype & rhs);
    void pop_front();
    void popback();

private :
    Celda*start;
    Celda*end;
    int tamano;
    void copiaProfunda(const List & otralis);

};




#endif /* LIST_H_ */
```

List.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;

template <typename datatype>
List<datatype>::List(){
    tamano = 0 ;
    start = end = new Celda;
    //miguel=2
}
template <typename datatype>
List<datatype>::~List(){
    Celda *cp = start;
        while (cp != NULL) {
            Celda *next = cp->siguiente;
            delete cp;
            cp = next;
        }
}

template <typename datatype>
List<datatype> & operator=(const List<datatype> & otralis ){
    if(this != otralis){
        Celda algo = new Celda; // Here doesnt recognize Celda as a class that is on the struct ! 
        Celda*cp = otralis.start;
        while (cp != NULL) {
                    Celda *siguiente2 = cp-> siguiente;
                    delete cp;
                    cp = next;
                }
        copiaprofunda(otralis);

    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename datatype>

int List<datatype>::size(){
    Celda*cp = start;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Change `List<datatype> & operator=` to `List<datatype> & List<datatype>::operator=`  It's a member function, you just forgot the class part.

Comment: Lol I am so dumb, Sound completely reasonable, thanks for the fast answer, Richard !.